# New data not picked up from S3 in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read data from an S3 bucket in Spark Structured Streaming. The below code works to get existing data. But, when new data is added to the bucket, Spark does not pick this.

```scala
val lines = spark.readStream.schema(schemaImp).format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("s3n://bucket/*")
val query = lines.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("memory").queryName("memtable").start()
query.processAllAvailable()
spark.sql("select * from memtable").show()
```

How can I make this work to fetch new data? Or, is this a feature that's not supported yet?

Answer (score 1):

Test against the local FS first. If it works there but not against S3, then it's some quirk with s3 rename/commit. If it doesn't work against a local FS, then it's how you are using streaming. Maybe try a test which logs whenever a .map() is invoked, so you can count actual use.

If you are using streaming and object stores, (a) use s3a over s3n, and (b) save straight into the object store path, instead of save + rename -you only need that to avoid processing of incomplete data on filesystems where files will be visible while they are being written

Comment: Tried the local file system and it's the same behavior. I'm guessing when I stream the output to a table in memory, the output does not pick up new data. I am trying to get around the limitation in structured streaming that prevents multiple aggregation operations on the input. If I can get the output streaming to pick up updates, I can do any number of aggregation operations. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I have uploaded the output log to [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nauda93y6nzz154/S3Table.log?dl=0). The part where a small table is displayed is picked up from the 1st file in S3. The lines below that are generated after I add a new file to S3. So, Spark does detect the new file, but does not stream the update to the output table.